# No need to import `!!!` operators into the package DESCRIPTION?

Tags: r, dplyr, devtools, rlang

I'm trying to build a package using `dplyr`. I extensively used `!!` and `!!!` operators from  `rlang`.

However, I didn't `import` them explicitly although the package seems to work nevertheless.

Am I missing something in the environment, or does `import(dplyr)` somehow cover this?

Comment: `dplyr` already imports them and you imported the entire `dplyr`. Seems ok in my opinion.

Comment: Those aren't regular R functions:  they are handled specially by the functions like `rlang::quo` that are imported and re-exported by `dplyr`.

Comment: Yeah, technically the R parser doesn't recognize `!!` and `!!!` as their own functions. It just sees multiple calls to the unary `!` function. The tidyverse chooses to reinterpret them in a special way through nonstandard evaluation. So since they aren't functions, you don't have to worry about importing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment above stated, `dplyr` re-exports tidyeval dependencies from `rlang`, so if you have `dplyr` in Imports you don't need to explicitly import `rlang`. However, it might be worth asking whether you need all of `dplyr`, or just the tidyeval parts - there's something to be said for keeping dependencies to a minimum. `rlang` is a very lightweight package dependency-wise, so if you can get away with depending only on it directly it can make your package faster to install and (in theory) less likely to break with an external update.

If you find yourself using a lot of quoting and unquoting operators in package development, you can also check out the [usethis package's "tidyverse development helpers"](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/tidyverse.html). `usethis::use_tidy_eval()` "imports a standard set of helpers to facilitate programming with the tidy eval toolkit." It's a quick and easy way to add `rlang` to Imports, and imports/re-exports and documents the `(en)quo(s)`, `(en)sym(s)`, `(en)expr(s)`, functions, `.data` pronoun, and `:=`. Then you should have what you need to use tidyeval throughout your package.